# How to add space between text at x-axis using ggplot package?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using ggplot package , i created the following barplot :

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = my_data$"ERP implementé", fill = my_data$"détectabilité")) +  geom_bar(width=0.1 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) +  labs(y = "fréquence de détectabilité", fill = "détectabilité", x = "ERP", title = "Fréquence de détectabilité / type d'ERP")
```

The output is the following :

[image]

The problem is in the x-axis , how can i add sufficient space between text labels at the x-axis such that it will be readable ?

```
levels(factor(my_data$"ERP implementé"))

 [1] "Aucun"                "Développé en interne" "IBM"                  "IFS"                 
 [5] "M3"                   "Microsoft Dynamics"   "Odoo (Open ERP)"      "ORACLE"              
 [9] "QAD"                  "SAGE"                 "SAP"
```

I wish my question is clear for you , thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Do you mean rotate the text? If so, add `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1, vjust = 1)` If you just want a space between the text and the axis add `xlab("\nERP")`

Comment: @TheSciGuy , yes the text should be readable ! that's all ! the problem is already solved and the question could be closed ! Thank you for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be playing with the orientation angle of labels like this:

```
#Code
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = my_data$"ERP implementé", fill = my_data$"détectabilité")) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.1 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) + 
  labs(y = "fréquence de détectabilité", fill = "détectabilité",
       x = "ERP", title = "Fréquence de détectabilité / type d'ERP")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

And a second option would be dodging your axis labels like this:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = my_data$"ERP implementé", fill = my_data$"détectabilité")) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.1 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) + 
  labs(y = "fréquence de détectabilité", fill = "détectabilité",
       x = "ERP", title = "Fréquence de détectabilité / type d'ERP")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge=2))
```

No output provided in lack of reproducible data.

Comment: Yes , this resolve the problem ! i tried also to change the plot orientation . The problem could be considered as resolved! Thank you for your valuable help !

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be :

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = my_data$"ERP implementé", fill = my_data$"détectabilité")) +  geom_bar(width=0.1 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) +  labs(y = "fréquence de détectabilité", fill = "détectabilité", x = "ERP", title = "Fréquence de détectabilité des problèmes selon type d'ERP")+coord_flip()
```

[image]

or even as mentionned in comments:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = my_data$"ERP implementé", fill = my_data$"détectabilité")) + 
  geom_bar(width=0.1 , position = position_dodge(width=0.5)) + 
  labs(y = "fréquence de détectabilité", fill = "détectabilité",
       x = "ERP", title = "Fréquence de détectabilité / type d'ERP")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90))
```

[image]